# Drag and Drop but replace <img> with inline svg

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, svg.js

I want to replace my images with inline SVG and have my code work. I have a simple drag and drop widget with a drag table and a drop table (it's really a drag and copy, which is how I want it). I have two images that have local .svg files with `draggable` set to `true`. I would like to make it so that the .svg code is inline so I can manipulate the svg's. Every time I've tried to replace `<img>` with `<svg>` the code breaks.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/jado66/rt5smfvz/9/:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Drag Drop SVG</title>
</head>
<style>

* {user-select: none; } 
.cell {width:50px;height:50px;
  }
img {width:50px;height:50px;cursor: move;}
table td #dropTable td:hover{background: #dedede;}
#dropTable {
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
}
.droppable:hover{
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#dropTable tbody { height:300px; overflow-y:auto;  }

</style>

<body>
   

     <!-- Drag Table -->
    
        <!-- <svg width="50" height="50">  //***!!!!***!!! I want to replace both <img> with inline <svg> and have my code work ***!!!!***!!!
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:6" />
        </svg> -->
        <table style="border-spacing: 5px;">
            <tr>
                <td id="svg1">
                    <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <img class = "droppable newGate" src="droppable newGate" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=1"   
                      ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id="1" draggable="true"/> </div>
                </td>
                <td id="svg2">
                    <div class = "cell " ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <img class = "droppable newGate" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=2"   
                      ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id="2" draggable="true" /> </div>
                </td>
    
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <!-- Drop Table -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="dropTable" >
                    <tr >
                        <td> <div class = "cell"></div></td> 
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <script>
    
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell:empty"); //We only want to add event listeners to empty cells
    for (const cell of cells){
        cell.addEventListener('dragover',allowDrop);
        cell.addEventListener('drop',drop);
    }
    
    function dragStart(evt)
    {
        evt.dataTransfer.setData("Text",evt.target.id);
    }
    
    function drop(evt)
    {
        var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
        nodeCopy.id = Date.now(); /* We cannot use the same ID */
        evt.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    }
    
    function allowDrop(ob)
    {
        ob.preventDefault();
    }
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Solution : Use jQuery :)

Comment: I would love an example lol

Comment: Sure, I just asked because most of people do not love jQuery because it is 32KB which might be slower a bit but I am writing an answer with jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is fine =) I'm writing a desktop application with Electron as my framework so the 32KB is nothing

Comment: God with you. Electron is very big in size. :)

Comment: See this : https://codepen.io/kevinmmansour/pen/Rwpaedp

Comment: It uses libraries called gsap.min.js and Draggable.min.js

Comment: This is a good start. I just really want to use a css grid and I'm not sure how I could implement  it with the codepen

Comment: I will try to implement both and give you example. :)

Comment: See this : https://jsfiddle.net/jpvamube/

Comment: I will complete Example but If you can add the local SVG in question. :)